# what is the error in this code using dataframe and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, sentiment-analysis

I have a python that read from CSV file and converts it to dataframe using pandas then using matplotlib  it plots a histogram. the first task is correct it read and write to and from CSV file.

the csv file fileds are:
date","user_loc","message","full_name","country","country_code","predictions","word count"

BUT the task of plotting is displaying the below error.

**Error:**

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
 last) <ipython-input-37-5bc3925ff988> in <module>
       1 #plot word count distribution for both positive and negative sentiment
 ----> 2 x= tweet_preds["word count"][tweet_preds.predictions ==1]
       3 y= tweet_preds["word count"][tweet_preds.predictions ==0]
       4 plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
       5 plt.xlim(0,45)

 IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
 numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

**Code:**

```
    # create of dataframe:
    #create column names
    col_names = ["date","user_loc","followers","friends","message","bbox_coords",
                 "full_name","country","country_code","place_type"]
    #read csv
    df_twtr = pd.read_csv("F:\AIenv\sentiment_analysis\paul_ryan_twitter.csv",names = col_names)
    #check head
    df_twtr=df_twtr.dropna()
    df_twtr = df_twtr.reset_index(drop=True)
    df_twtr.head()


# run predictions on twitter data
tweet_preds = model_NB.predict(df_twtr['message'])

# append predictions to dataframe
df_tweet_preds = df_twtr.copy()
df_tweet_preds['predictions'] = tweet_preds
df_tweet_preds.shape

    df_tweet_preds = pd.DataFrame(df_tweet_preds,columns = ["date","user_loc","message","full_name","country","country_code","predictions","word count"])
    df_tweet_preds = df_tweet_preds.drop(["user_loc","country","country_code"],axis=1)
    df_tweet_preds_to_csv = df_tweet_preds.to_csv(r'F:\AIenv\sentiment_analysis\export_dataframe.csv', index = False, header=True)

     #plot word count distribution for both positive and negative sentiment
    x= tweet_preds["word count"][tweet_preds.predictions ==1]
    y= tweet_preds["word count"][tweet_preds.predictions ==0]
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
    plt.xlim(0,45)
    plt.xlabel("word count")
    plt.ylabel("frequency")
    g = plt.hist([x,y],color=["r","b"],alpha=0.5,label=["positive","negative"])
    plt.legend(loc="upper right")
```

Comment: what happens when you print `tweet_preds["word count"][tweet_preds.predictions ==1]` on its own ?

Comment: @Datanovice it display the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a dataframe, it is a numpy array. The result of your predict() method is a numpy array which cannot be indexed like you are trying to. Why not just use the dataframe that you append the prediction to, 'df_tweet_preds['predictions'] = tweet_preds'. Then you can do all sorts of indexing.

Comment: i tried your answer and this error shows.

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'loc'`

Comment: I assumed 'tweet_preds' was a pandas dataframe. Maybe you could show how 'tweet_preds' is created because it looks by the code that you are treating it as a pandas df not a numpy array.

Comment: yes it a dataframe i will  add the code to my question

Comment: It is not a dataframe, it is a numpy array. The result of your predict() method is a numpy array which cannot be indexed like you are trying to. Why not just use the dataframe that you append the prediction to, 'df_tweet_preds['predictions'] = tweet_preds'. Then you can do all sorts of indexing.

Comment: thank you this was the error i did not notice that its not a dataframe.